# IE 11 bug, div with height > 1,533,917px display negative computed height and doesnt render

Tags: height, internet-explorer-11, computed-style

jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/FPkxn/2/
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="Display"/>
<div id="Container" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px; width: 115px;overflow-x: hidden;">
<div id="HugeDiv" style="background-color:red;width:100px;height:3000000px"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript (JQuery):

```
var Display = $("#Display");

$("#Container").scroll(function(){
    Display.val($(this).scrollTop());
});

console.log($("#HugeDiv").height());
```

This wont display on browser! it will display -184070.03 in computed height 
and the real height will be 1,533,917px.

¿Why? Firefox display the height as expected.

¿any work around?

Thanks

Comment: also noticed that when you hide the element (display: none), computer height reflects proper height.